# App receiving LiveData from Service in same apk (process) -Bad practice or not?

Tags: android-service, android-livedata

I have a service that collects data and has to survive the app's life-cycle changes while app is in the background. This service resides in the same process as my app, i.e. registered in the manifest as well.

The service posts LiveData to the app, and the main app retrieves this LiveData by binding to the service and doing something like:

```
private void onServiceConnected(TicketValidatorService service) {
    ...
    service.getStatus().observe(this, new Observer<SomeStatus>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(SomeStatus status) {
            handleStatusChanged(status);
        }
    })
    ...
}
```

Is this considered bad practice? Or should I rather communicate via Messenger/Handler or LocalBroadcastManager stuff over the service/app boundary? It would be difficult to put the service in another process, but I don't think I have to do that for the sake of my task.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with that, if your service is not accessible outside your own app scope there's little reason to force it into separate process.

Answer (score 0):

Communication to a local service directly is not considered to be a bad practice and in fact an [official recommendation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services#Binder). There is no reason to complicate your code to support cross-process communication when you are not going to use it. Moreover this kind of communication involves marshaling / unmarshaling which adds restrictions on data types you can pass through and has some performance hit.

Also please note, starting from android 8 there are [limitations](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background#services) on background services. So if you are not running your service as a foreground service it's not going to be alive for long time after your app goes to background.